# Carthage image not found Xcode 7 Carthage 0.8.0

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, carthage

Currently I'm using Carthage Dependency manager, and Everything works fine. Until I Run the code on my simulator. I get the following error message.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/OAuthSwift.framework/OAuthSwift
  Referenced from: /Users/eddwinpaz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/117C3ED9-5B0A-4FCD-B231-5E9BC0ADF821/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/1FC4FA99-7479-44D1-BB71-1A52404BDB4C/App.app/App
  Reason: image not found
(lldb)
```

I've followed the steps on the following tutorial.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/109330/carthage-tutorial-getting-started

I must also mention that I installed manually the Carthage.pgk of Carthage and then removed it and install it via Brew.

There is something I'm forgetting to do?

Comment: Try cleaning the project / build, sometimes that works

Answer (score 0):

There can be multiple causes. One cause can be that the framework is being linked with the framework but the framework is not being embedded in the app bundle. The compiler will happily link it for you but the dynamic loader will not find the framework’s image (i.e., binary) at launch.

To resolve this issue, select the project in the Project Navigator, select the app target in the list of targets, select the “Build Phases” tab, and add the framework in the “Embed Frameworks” list. If the framework is already in the list, the problem lies elsewhere.

[image: Adding RxSwift and RxCocoa to the “Embed Frameworks” build phase]